# I have a question about Elzaki variational iteration method.

Tags: integration, functions, partial-derivative, fundamental-solution

How to get from the first line to the second line?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3nxrx.jpg)

> $$u_{n+1}(x,t) = u_n (x,t) - \int_0^t \left\{ (u_n)_s(x,s) - \frac{\partial}{\partial s} G(x,s) + \frac{\partial}{\partial s}E^{-1} \left\{ vE \left[ N u_n(x,s) \right] \right\} \right\}\, ds$$
>   Or alternatively
>   $$
> u_{n+1}(x,t) = G(x,t) - E^{-1} \left\{ vE \left[Nu_n (x,t) \right] \right\}
> $$

Comment: Is $(u_n)_s$the same as ${\partial \over \partial s} (u_n)$?

Comment: Yes, (un)s is the same as ∂∂s(un)

Comment: OK, so you are integrating a differential, $\int {d(F)\over dx} dx$

Comment: can you prove to show me?